# Snake game, increasing length in processing

Tags: java, processing

I am trying to recreate the snake game, right now i am stuck on adding a new section to the snake everything it collides with an apple

I tried to tell the program to draw a new rectangle but with the x axis slightly shifted and this "shifting" would slowly increase every time my snake eats an apple. My snake starts off with 2 sections, and when i move the snake towards the green apple, it only moves the second section instead of drawing a new one, I know i didn't tell my draw method to draw a new rectangle every time my snake eats an apple since i have no clue on how to do that

```
public void draw(PApplet p) {
    // clear area
    p.fill(255, 0, 0);

    // draw snake head
    p.rect(x, y, length, width);

    // draw snake body ?
    if (upIsDown == true ) {
        p.rect(x, y - section, length, width);
    } else if(downIsDown == true) {
        p.rect(x, y + section, length, width);
    } else if(RightIsDown == true) {
        p.rect(x - section, y, length, width);
    } else if(LeftIsDown == true) {
        RightIsDown = false;
        p.rect(x + section, y, length, width);
    }
}
```

the section variable increases by 10 in my `checkCollision` method

The snake gets longer, but my program only draws the head and the tail of the snake

Comment: Since you seem new to programming, you could start by reading and understanding other implementations of this, such as here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24324781/,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23509500,
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/129719, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/151800

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java snake game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24324781/java-snake-game)

Answer (score 2):

I added comments to your code.

You code in draw clears the whole game area, then draws 2 rectangles. If you want to see 3 rectanges, you will need to call `p.rect()` 3 times in that method. If you want to see 10 rectanges, you will need to call it 10 times (so maybe a loop would be good). Else reconsider the call to `p.fill()` in the beginning.

For a loop, you would need to store the coordinates for each body segment in a structure like a LinkedList, with the coordinates for each segment, and in the draw method draw all segments.